# Android Image Slider using Viewpageindicator and UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, eclipse, slideshow, universal-image-loader, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to create an Image Slider that Images list come from api. I wanna use viewpagerindicator to navigate between pages and UniversalImageLoading for lazy loading.

I've tried viewpagerindicator official examples which are made to show text ("this is a test") in the views but not image I can replace it's text view with image view but since I need lazy loading  I decided not to reinvent the wheel so do you have any idea or any sample that meet my needs???

I'm a bit newbie to android so it's difficult for me to combine components. I **use eclipse** and my view is simple only one image view and pager for dots on bottom of the page just like the **video below** it's really what I need

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7PrF-GsgFw

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this link , it is very good and you can program it for infinite pager indicator.

[Follow this link](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/looping-infinite-viewpager-with-page-indicator-in-android-ce741f25702a#.ykpjk6kzo)

Comment: thanks but it's not what I need. I need Image Slider with lazy loading in fact combination of viewpagerindicator and universal image loader